# Chart with Zooming Functionality

Tags: ios, objective-c, graph, charts, uiscrollview

I have to make graph like below :

[image]

Somehow using bezierPath, CAShapeLayer and animation i managed to make the graph. But now want to add zooming functionality. Zooming code is below :

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return _graphView;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollV withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale
{
    [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scale*320, scale*1700)];
}
```

When i scroll horizontally everything is ok, but for vertically please check the image below :

[image]

Note : X and Y axis are on the view and the graph is on the scrollview, i also want to change the xand y coordinates according to zooming and also make it scrollable. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**See this below :**

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat offsetX = MAX((scrollView.bounds.size.width - scrollView.contentSize.width) * 0.5, 0.0);
    CGFloat offsetY = MAX((scrollView.bounds.size.height - scrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.5, 0.0);

    _drawingView.center = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentSize.width * 0.5 + offsetX,
                                 scrollView.contentSize.height * 0.5 + offsetY);


    return _drawingView;
}
```